# Нужна ли вторая запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему одни, некогда популярные продукты, вытесняют другие?

Answer (score 2):

Нет обособления: Почему **одни некогда популярные** продукты вытесняют другие?

Здесь "одни некогда популярные" – **неоднородные** определения (местоимение + прилагательное с зависимым словом).

Один  –  **местоимение** со значением "какой-нибудь в ряду сходных предметов".

**Дополнение**

Вообще говоря, смысл предложения не очень ясен. Можно предложить два варианта:

(1) Почему одни, **некогда популярные**, продукты **вытесняются** другими? (2) Почему  одни продуты, **некогда популярные**, **вытесняются** другими?

Здесь обособление позволяет показать, что оборот относится только к первым продуктам.

Comment: А если смысл такой: одни продукты, некогда популярные, вытесняют другие (ранее себя не проявлявшие)? Без запятых выходит, что и те, и другие некогда были популярны. А первый (более вероятный) смысл разве нельзя выразить без перестановки слов (не запятыми, так скобками)?

Comment: Да, со смыслом здесь проблемы, поэтому я исправила ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении вообще не нужны запятые: ***Почему одни некогда популярные продукты вытесняют другие?*** Здесь нет ни уточнения, ни причастного ни деепричастного оборота.